# sbt, ivy, offline work, and weirdness

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, ivy

I'm trying to work on an sbt project offline (again). Things almost seem to be ok, but there are strange things that I'm baffled by. Here's what I'm noticing:

I've created an empty sbt project and am considering the following dependencies in build.sbt:

```
name := "sbtSand"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.1",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2"
)
```

I've built the project while online, and can see all the packages in [userhome]/.ivy2/cache. The project builds fine. I then turn off wifi, sbt clean and attempt to build. The build fails. I comment out the spark dependency (keeping the joda-time one). Still offline, I run sbt compile. The project builds fine. I put the spark dependency back in, and sbt clean. It again fails to build. I get back online. I can build again.

The sbt output for the failed builds are like: https://gist.github.com/ashic/9e5ebc39ff4eb8c41ffb

The key part of it is:

`[info] Resolving org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-app;2.2.0 ...
[warn] Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app/2.2.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.2.0.pom
[info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.`

It's interesting that sbt is managing to use the joda-time from ivy cache, but for the spark-core package (or rather its dependency) it wants to reach out to the internet and fails the build. Could anybody please help me understand this, and what I can do so that I can get this to work while fully offline?

Comment: I've also tried adding scalatest in "test". That worked offline too.

Comment: Are you using sbt's `-offline` flag?

Comment: If you mean "set offline := true", then yes - I've tried it. From what I gather, it only applies to snapshots, and I'm not using any.

Comment: @ashic Note that _joda-time_ has a mandatory dependency on _joda-convert_ when used from Scala that is defined as _optional_ in its _POM_. Hence you must declare that dependency yourself. See https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.1/joda-time-2.9.1.pom and search for _mandatory_. IIRC not including that dependency can lead to strange behaviour that's tricky to trace down, I don't remember why the _POM_ is as it is, but I blame maven ;-) HTH. P.S. Here's an explanation http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/10575

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is resolved in 0.13.9. I was using 0.13.8. [The 0.13.9 msi for windows seemed to give me 0.13.8, while the 0.13.9.2 msi installed the right version. Existing projects need updating manually to 0.13.9 in build properties.]

Comment: So I wasn't totally crazy.... the issues were in perfect alignment for my scenario to arise!